# Ошибка lxn/walk undefined: win.MB.APPLMODAL

Tags: windows, golang

При установке lxn/walk выдает ошибки

```
# github.com/lxn/walk 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:41:42: undefined: win.MB_APPLMODAL 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:42:42: undefined: win.MB_SYSTEMMODAL 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:43:42: undefined: win.MB_TASKMODAL 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:44:42: undefined: win.MB_HELP 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:45:42: undefined: win.MB_SETFOREGROUND 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:46:42: undefined: win.MB_DEFAULT_DESKTOP_ONLY 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:47:42: undefined: win.MB_TOPMOST 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:48:42: undefined: win.MB_RIGHT 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:49:42: undefined: win.MB_RTLREADING 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:50:42: undefined: win.MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION 
C:\github.com\lxn\walk\messagebox.go:50:42: too many errors
```

Чего ему не хватает? Даже SDK поставил, не помогает.
ОС Windows 10 (1803)

Comment: Попробуйте откатить `walk` до версии пораньше. Насколько мне известно ребята там сейчас ативно работают над улучшением и изменением пакета, так что master-ветка не стабильна. Какой-то февральский коммит у меня на Windows 10 работал нормально.

Comment: Так на одном компе нормально стоит, правда там у меня LTSB, а на простой Win10Pro выдает такую ошибку